# What is the meaning of 之手 in 每组中一幅出自著名抽象艺术家之手?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

志愿者的任务很简单，每个人会看到两两一组出现的一些图画，每组中一幅出自著名抽象艺术家之手，另一幅是业余爱好者、婴儿、黑猩猩或者大象的涂鸦。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 18.

What is the meaning of 之手? His hand? 之 has many meanings, while 手 I suppose means hand. I know the 之 as the third-person pronoun: him, her, it, them. Does it make sense here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

之 here is a more literary version of 的 (possessive marker) XX之手= hand of XX or XX's hand

[**出自**] XX [**之手**] (from XX's hand) = [**by**] XX

[**出自**]著名抽象艺术家[**之手**] = [**by**] famous abstract artist

More example of 之手 (hand of):

[**借**]XX[**之手**] (borrow XX's hand) = [**use**] XX to

曹操[**借**]孙权[**之手**]杀关羽 = Cao Cao[**used**] Sun Quan to kill Guan Yu

Notice: *you can replace 借(borrow) with the more literary 假(borrow)*

Answer (score 0):

"出自....之手" = drew/written/made by....